# Проблема с выводом через метод Python

Tags: python, функции, методы

Практиковал навыки на простой игрушке и столкнулся с проблемой вывода

Есть такой метод. Дело в том что когда к нему обращаются (bot.whoWins(bot, alex)), он выполняет все правильно, но выводит он далеко не то что нужно.

Надо что бы выводил - Камень бьет ножницы, выиграл игрок 1 bot

А выводит оно - Камень бьет ножницы, выиграл игрок 1 <player.Player object at 0x0000027E05595B40>

```
def whoWins(self,First,Secound):
    self.First = First
    self.Secound = Secound
    if First.Choise == Secound.Choise:
        print("Ничья")
    elif First.Choise == Variants.Rock:
        if Secound.Choise == Variants.Scissors:
             print("Камень бьет ножницы, выиграл игрок 1 ",First)
        else:
             print("Бумага оборачивает камень, выиграл игрок 2 ",Secound)
```

Comment: Вероятно, надо написать `First.Name` или как называется свойство с именем игрока

Comment: оо, спасибо, я как то сразу не додумался

Comment: Лучше всё-таки реализовать у класса `Player` метод `__str__` и там возвращать то, что вы хотите, чтобы выводилось, когда делают `print(player)`, где `player` - экземпляр класса `Player`. Например, пусть там будет `return self.Name`.

Comment: Спасибо, выглядит гораздо лучше

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так.

```
def whoWins(self,First,Secound):
    First = self.First
    Secound = self.Secound
    if First.Choise == Secound.Choise:
        print("Ничья")
    elif First.Choise == Variants.Rock:
        if Secound.Choise == Variants.Scissors:
             print("Камень бьет ножницы, выиграл игрок 1 ",First)
        else:
             print("Бумага оборачивает камень, выиграл игрок 2 ",Secound)
```